# streaming a mp4 file using RTSP?

Tags: android, video-streaming

I am developing an app. that will stream the video recorded from camera and stored as mp4 in sdcard...

I know there something called as RTSP which is used for that...
Please tell me where to start . .and is there any library that will do this for me...

Comment: thanks,, But i want to make a project like spydroid on google code repository....I am able to record video and saving it on the sdcard , but i want to stream this and the device is going to act as server and the streaming shoud be realtime...

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you want to stream a local mp4 file, but maybe I misunderstood you problem. RTSP is used for live streaming, but you want to play a local mp4 file.

If you want to capture video and save it as mp4 onto a SD card, you need to use the Android MediaRecorder. [Here a link to a simple example](http://android-er.blogspot.dk/2011/04/simple-exercise-of-video-capture-using.html).

If you just want to playback a local mp4 file. Have a look at the Android API Demos.
These are part of the Android SDK installation and contain a good example of how to playback local media files.