# Android: Streaming local video on my SD Card using spydroid

Tags: android, video, stream, rtsp

Since i can record my stream on my client phone using Spydroid [here](http://code.google.com/p/spydroid-ipcamera/source/checkout) from another phone. now i want to stream through rtsp my local recorded .mp4 file using spydroid for example i had a /mount/sdcard/vid.mp4...and i want to play it through rtsp from another phone.

My questions Are:

*is this possible? if its not what class will i need to modify from spydroid?

*can i just use a .mp4 file for stream rather than the camerastream or do i need to convert them to another format?

*Does the video stream class create a video file while streaming? or it just passes data through packet directly?

any opinions and solutions will be appreciated especially if sample codes similar to my questions thank you.

Edited:
I tried to modify the code for VideoStream.java and replace the mPacketizer.setinputstream from my local file and the error comes on

> 01-23 17:49:06.960: E/H263Packetizer(646): Couldn't skip mp4 header :/

here is my code:

```
    File file= new File("/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/samp.3gp");
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(file);

               //       mMediaRecorder.prepare();
                   //       mMediaRecorder.start();

    try {
           // mReceiver.getInputStream contains the data from the camera
    // the mPacketizer encapsulates this stream in an RTP stream and send it over the network
        mPacketizer.setDestination(mDestination, mRtpPort, mRtcpPort);
           //           mPacketizer.setInputStream(mReceiver.getInputStream());
        mPacketizer.setInputStream(stream);
        mPacketizer.start();
        mStreaming = true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        stop();
        throw new IOException("Something happened with the local sockets :/ Start failed !");
    }

}
```

Comment: @Sandeep Dhull- Hello sir i find this similar in your last [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11204922/streaming-a-mp4-file-using-rtsp) i just wonder if you can help me or guide me on how you solve this problem and will be really grateful if you share your code for study purposes thank you.

Comment: @Ralf- Hello sir i am just wondering if you can help me with my question thank you.